# Is there a differentiable alternative to K.cast?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

For a custom Keras loss function, I need to create a float tensor from a bool tensor. Unfortunately, K.cast() is not differentiable and therefore can't be used. Is there an alternative way to do this that is differentiable?

```
less_than_tau = y_pred < tau
less_than_tau = K.cast(less_than_tau, 'float32')
```

Comment: No, there is no way to do that, casting itself conceptually it is not differentiable (its not a continuous function). Comparisons like that are also not differentiable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dr. Snoopy is right.

The way you solve for this in deep learning is "soft" functions, such as softmax instead of max.

In your case, if you want to minimize y-pred relative y-tau, you'd do something like

```
switch = sigmoid(y_pred - y_tau)
loss = switch * true_case + (1. - switch) * false_case
```

Comment: Thank you! I replaced it with 
`temp = y_pred - tau`,  `temp = tf.keras.activations.relu(temp)`, `less_than_tau = (tf.sign(temp) - 1.0) * -1.0`